# How to implement Levenshtein algorithmin Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, foreach, nested, apache-pig, levenshtein-distance

I have two datasets. 
A {(1,apple),(2,orange),(3,banana)} and B={(1,oracle),(2,ape),(3,naana),(4,orlando),(5,app)(6,banner)}

I have a udf which gives Levenshtein score between two strings. But how to calculate every field in A with all the fields in B to get most matched string in B.

eg., Levenshtein score of 'apple' in A is more for app than ape in B
     Levenshtein score of 'orange' in A is more for oracle than orlando in B
     Levenshtein score of 'banana' in A is more for naana than banner in B.

Comment: Did you write the UDF for Levenshtein yourself? What are the options to write it; directly in Pig Latin or can you write in a language like Python for example? Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably do a `CROSS`. Then compute the Lvenshtein distance for each pair and find out the maximum for each.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#cross